# Push notification - I see date of received of the notification, not date of sending the notification

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I send push notification follow with https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message :

```
var registrationToken = 'bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...';

var payload = {
  notification: {
    title: 'Urgent action needed!',
    body: 'Urgent action is needed to prevent your account from being disabled!'
  }
};

var options = {
  priority: 'high',
  timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
};

admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload, options)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

I receive notification on my phone (android react native app), but on the lock screen i see the date of the notification reception, not the date when the notification was sent.

For example, it happens when I receive notification after phone recover connection.

Comment: As i understand from your question. You want to display the time of the notification that is sent. You can send the `EPOCH` time in the payload and extract the same while displaying the notification.

Comment: That sounds like an answer Rahul! :)